# nohupを付けても付けなくても何故か切断されない

Tags: linux, bash

いつもお世話になっております。

CentOSにて、端末切断後もサンプルスクリプトを継続実行できているか検証しておりました。

どちらの検証も継続して処理されてしまいました。

&だけでも継続処理されnohup不要になったのでしょうか？

nohupを付けても何かしらのシグナルを検知し、initプロセス管理下になってしまいました。

色々調べたのですが解決できなく質問させて頂きました。
ご教授ご鞭撻のほどよろしくお願い致します。

サンプルスクリプト

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
while :
do
    echo "$i"
    sleep 1
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

サンプルスクリプト（readバージョン）

```
#!/bin/bash
file=/var/log/messages
while read line
do
    echo $line
    sleep 1
done < $file
```

検証１（バックグラウンドジョブのみ）

```
# ./test.sh > out.txt &
[1] 19363
# exit

別端末より
# ps -ef | grep -v grep | egrep -e 19363 -e 19348
root     19363     1  0 16:43 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh  ...initプロセス(1)が面倒を見た
root     19760 19363  0 16:46 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 1

fork()観点だとinitプロセス管理化でゾンビ退治してくれる正常動作？？
```

検証２（nohup + バックグラウンドジョブ）

```
# nohup ./test.sh > out.txt &
[1] 20448
# exit

別端末より
# ps -ef | grep -v grep | egrep -e 20448 -e 20410
root     20448     1  0 16:52 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh  ...nohup付けてもinitプロセス管理下
root     20799 20448  0 16:55 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 1
```

環境

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
```

以上よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: ログインシェルが bash だとすれば、`huponexit` が off になっているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。確認しましたらoffになっておりました。&だけでも継続処理される理由だったのですね。ありがとうございます！

Comment: nohupに関する動作を調査されているなら、一読をおすすめします
https://www.glamenv-septzen.net/view/854
詳細な解説が掲載されています

Comment: コメントの内容で解決したのであれば、お手数ですが自分でその内容を回答として投稿してもらえないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ログインシェルが`bash`の場合、`huponexit`の値が`off`になっているのではないでしょうか。

nohupに関する動作を調査されているなら、こちらも参考になります：[なぜnohupをバックグランドジョブとして起動するのが定番なのか？(擬似端末, Pseudo Terminal, SIGHUP他)](https://www.glamenv-septzen.net/view/854)

([metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis)さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38798/nohup%E3%82%92%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E4%BD%95%E6%95%85%E3%81%8B%E5%88%87%E6%96%AD%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/51347#comment39069_38798)および[gocho](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9796/gocho)さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38798/nohup%E3%82%92%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E4%BD%95%E6%95%85%E3%81%8B%E5%88%87%E6%96%AD%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/51347#comment39072_38798)より)